# Module '"mongoose"' has no exported member 'PaginateResult'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I can't seem to add `mongoose-paginate` types to my `angular-cli` project setup with Angular 4. Webpack is throwing

```
import {PaginateResult} from "mongoose";

...

getAll(page: number): Observable<PaginateResult<Operation>> {
    ...
}
```

Ctrl-clicking `PaginateResult` in Webstorm opens the correct file definition. The types are correctly installed in the `node_modules/@types` directory (I installed them using `npm install --save @types/mongoose-paginate`).

However, webpack is throwing:

```
ERROR in /Users/geoffroy/dev/git/ezvat/client4/src/app/components/operations/operation.service.ts (8,9): Module '"mongoose"' has no exported member 'PaginateResult'.
```

What is going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the `mongoose-paginate` module

```
import * as mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate';
```

It seems that the correct namespaces are not found without importing it. I found it using the test in the DefinitelyTyped repo https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose-paginate/mongoose-paginate-tests.ts

Comment: Fixed it :D Thanks !